# Drag and drop with Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to implement dragging and dropping an element in a Xamarin Forms project? I thought this would be simple but I cant seem to find anything online about it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty light on samples for it actually.  Here's a Xamarin forms list view (not by me) with dnd to get you started.

https://github.com/isychev93/Xamarin.Forms-Drag-and-drop-ListView